# How do I access the folder in Mac os?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Me and my friend were playing minecraft and decided we should get forge. For me, it worked perfectly, however it didn't for him. it kept crashing everytime. I tried using teamviewer and find the .minecraft folder, however, I couldn't find anywhere. How do I access it on Mac Os X?

Comment: Looks like either [I don't have a Minecraft folder anywhere on my Mac](//gaming.stackexchange.com/q/294910) or [Is the .minecraft folder hidden on a Mac?](//gaming.stackexchange.com/q/115943) may already have answers for this. Do either of those answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

Open up a terminal window (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app) and run the following command `open ~/Library/Application\ Support/minecraft/`. It will open a Finder window in the Minecraft folder. The user Library folder has been hidden for a few versions of macOS, so you will have to use the terminal, or optionally unhide the Library folder in your home folder (can be done by opening your home folder, right-click, `Show View Options>Check 'Show Library Folder'`). Though a fair word of warning, even if you are both using macOS you wont be able to copy your forge installation to your friend's computer, so accessing this folder will only really be useful for deleting Forge/Minecraft.